# ActionListener running before focus listener

Tags: java, swing, listener, actionlistener, focuslistener

I have an application in which there is a textbox and a button. the textbox has focusListener(for incorrect values) and the button has actionListener(for saving the value into a file). 
An error message window pops up when a wrong value is entered in the textfield as soon as it loses focus. Now I have 2 senarios.

1. when the focus is lost from tab out and if a wrong value is entered in the field then the pop up window shows up correctly.
2. But when i enter a wrong value in the field and without tab out I click the button then the actionListener is activated before the focusListener(Focus Lost) and it saves the wrong value in the text file and then shows the error message.

How should I stop the incorrect value to be saved into file by running the focuslistener first?

Answer (score 2):

> ActionListener running before focus listener

- [Focus, FocusListener, Focus Subsystem is asyncronous](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#transferTiming), you can sheduling those events, but can caused another side effects, I'd suggest don't do that
- delay required events in EDT by using `invokeLater`,

Comment: I tried with invokelater inside actionlistener but still didnt get  what I wanted.                                                    `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {   
public void run() {
if(componentManager.textField.getText().equals("")){}});)`